# animating mesh division and holes

Tags: animation, mesh, shape-keys

I'm doing some mesh morphs using shape keys and the shrink wrap modifier with sub surf to get the mesh to mold to the shape of things i want it to shape into. the problem is when i have things with loops, holes, and separate pieces. whats the best way To go about animating dividing mesh and holes.

i drew this quick little sketch example of what i'm after showing a sphere turning into a doughnut.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use boolean modifier and animate the boolean object to cut your mesh.